# Macro's in mhchem?

Tags: mhchem

I want to write hydroxyl radicals quite frequently, so I thought of making a small macro. But with the macro, the text is not processed as chemical compounds in the `mhchem` package. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\ohrad{OH^{.}}

\begin{document}

This is with the macro \ce{\ohrad}, this is without the macro \ce{OH^{.}}

\end{document}
```

and the output

[image]

Comment: This is perfectly normal, I'm afraid: `\ce` starts scanning token by token and what it finds is not a letter to be typeset upright, but a control sequence and it does nothing with it; but eventually TeX expands it (in math mode).

Comment: Use `\newcommand\ohrad{\cf{OH^{.}}}`. Macros reveal `\ce` innards: math mode... but `mhchem`'s formulae are nestable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And according to @cgnieder it should work to use `\cf{}`. And it does:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\ohrad{\cf{OH^{.}}}

\begin{document}

This is with the macro \ce{\ohrad}, this is without the macro \ce{OH^{.}}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This adds a prefix `\^` which causes the following macro to be expanded (once) while `\ce` is scanning.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\makeatletter
\let\old@mhchem@ce@i\mhchem@ce@i
\def\mhchem@ce@i{%
\ifx\mhchem@ce@lookahead\^%
   \expandafter\mhc@expand
\else
   \expandafter\old@mhchem@ce@i
\fi}
\def\mhc@expand\^{\expandafter\mhchem@ce@continue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\ohrad{OH^{.}}

\begin{document}


This is with the macro \ce{\^\ohrad}, this is without the macro \ce{OH^{.}}

\end{document}
```